# database file can't be found

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am trying to use dataBAseHelper class to create database file, but i cant find it on data file (it stills empty). while debugging it, it seems that onCreate method doesn't been called  .
i tried different databaseHelper versions,but it didnt work.
you can see my code below (MAinActivity & DataBaseHelper classes):

#### The DatabaseHelper class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tasks.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "task_table";
    public static final String ID_COL = "ID";
    public static final String NAME_COL = "NAME";
    public static final String CATEGORY_COL = "CATEGORY";
    public static final String DURATION_COL = "DURATION";
    public static final String DATETIME_COL = "DATETIME";
    public static final String DESCRIPTION_COL = "DATETIME";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_TABLE_TASKS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME  + "("
                + ID_COL + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + NAME_COL + " TEXT, "
                + DATETIME_COL + " TEXT,"
                + DURATION_COL + " INTEGER,"
                + CATEGORY_COL + " TEXT,"
                + DESCRIPTION_COL + " TEXT " + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_TASKS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean insertData(Task task) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME_COL,task.getName());
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COL,task.getCategory().toString());
        contentValues.put(DATETIME_COL,task.getDateTime());
        contentValues.put(DURATION_COL,task.getDuration());
        contentValues.put(DESCRIPTION_COL,task.getDescription());

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null ,contentValues);
        if(result == -1)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    public Cursor getAllData() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }

    public boolean updateData(String id,Task task) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ID_COL,id);
        contentValues.put(CATEGORY_COL,task.getCategory().toString());
        contentValues.put(DATETIME_COL,task.getDateTime());
        contentValues.put(DURATION_COL,task.getDuration());
        contentValues.put(DESCRIPTION_COL,task.getDescription());
        db.update(TABLE_NAME, contentValues, "ID = ?",new String[] { id });
        return true;
    }

    public Integer deleteData (String id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.delete(TABLE_NAME, "ID = ?",new String[] {id});
    }
}
```

#### The MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DatabaseHelper data;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         data = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.item,menu);
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, addActivity.class);
   // startActivity(intent);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.add:

                Intent  intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,addActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually have to do something with the database for the `onCreate` method to be invoked; as opposed to just creating an instance of the database helper (more specifically do something that opens the database using either `getWriteableDatabase` or `getReadableDatabase`).

So try adding a line such as `data.insert(new task(paremateres_to_construct_the task);`

Alternately you could change the databasehelper constructor to invoke one of the methods and therefore cause the `onCreate` method to be invoked. e.g. :-

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    this.getWriteableDatabase();
}
```

The latter will create an empty table, the former will create the table an add a row. Doing both would not be an issue.

Comment: i found a mistake:  
  public static final String DATETIME_COL = "DATETIME";
  public static final String DESCRIPTION_COL = "DATETIME";


i fixed it , but even i still fails.

Comment: i tried both of the solution that you offered , but it didnt work

Comment: If you make a change then to get `onCreate` to run you have to either delete the App's data, uninstall the app or increase the database version as `onCreate` is only automatically called for a new database (first two will delete the database, increasing the database version  causes the `onUpgrade` method to run which calls `onCreate`; database vesion is the  4th parameter of `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` i.e. the **1**).